# html form, newbie error

Tags: html, forms

I have two html files namely "file1.html" and "file2.html". File1 is supposed to encode a string written in an input file and send it to file2 via URL so that it could be decoded there.

My problem is an embarrassing one as I'm having trouble while passing from file1 to file2. Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function encode()
{
    var encodeThis = document.getElementById("exampleText").value;
    document.getElementById("exampleText").value = escape(escape(encodeThis));
}
</script>
</head>

<body>

<form name="input" action="file2.html" method="get">
<input id="exampleText" type="text" name="example" value="Not strongly encoded" />
<input type="button" value="Encode and Submit!" onclick="encode()" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

When I click to submit button, I expect to send the encoded string via URL and pass to file2.html where I can process it, however I remain at my first page: "file1.html". Which fundamental knowledge do I lack here ? Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because there is no submit. Either you give the input-tag the type submit instead of button or you make a form.submit () via JS.

`document.input.submit();` should do this.

BTW... why double-escape?

Comment: Oh my god thx a lot ^^
Will fill in the encode function properly later on, double escape is just for testing.

Answer (score 1):

The submit button should be like this:

```
<input type="submit" value="Encode and Submit!" onclick="encode()" />
```

Comment: @vaisakh You misunderstand how inline event handlers work. Browser internally rewrites the `onclick` HTML attribute to something like `<input>.onclick = function() { with (document) { with (this) { encode(); } } };` - you can ignore the `with` constructs for now but what's more important is that this function still returns `undefined` and `return true` at the end of `encode` function makes no difference.

Comment: @duri thanks for that info. +1 . I used to write `return true` just to be sure. I will edit this now.